# How to get trace from 'type' (windows) using Boost.Process?

Tags: c++, windows, boost, command-line, process

I wanted to use Boost.Process ([docs I used](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/process/tutorials.html#process.tutorials.pipeline) [source I used](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/process/)) to create some service but while testing the lib found out that I cant even trace a simple cmd app like `type` (note: inside same folder I start my app from `type "./config.xml"` works perfectly).

What I have tried:

I tried sync:

```
#include <boost/process.hpp> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream> 

namespace bp = ::boost::process; 

bp::child start_child() 
{ 
    std::string exec = "type \"./config.xml\""; 

    std::vector<std::string> args; 

    bp::context ctx; 
    ctx.stdout_behavior = bp::capture_stream(); 

    return bp::launch_shell(exec, args, ctx); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    bp::child c = start_child(); 

    bp::pistream &is = c.get_stdout(); 
    std::string line; 
    while (std::getline(is, line)) 
        std::cout << line << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

and also async:

```
#if defined(__CYGWIN__) 
#  define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 
#  define __USE_W32_SOCKETS 
#  undef BOOST_POSIX_API 
#  define BOOST_WINDOWS_API 
#endif 
#include <boost/asio.hpp> 
#define BOOST_PROCESS_WINDOWS_USE_NAMED_PIPE 
#include <boost/process.hpp> 
#include <boost/array.hpp> 
#include <boost/bind.hpp> 
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream> 

namespace bp = ::boost::process; 
namespace ba = ::boost::asio; 

ba::io_service io_service; 
boost::array<char, 4096> buffer; 

#if defined(BOOST_POSIX_API) 
ba::posix::stream_descriptor in(io_service); 
#elif defined(BOOST_WINDOWS_API) 
ba::windows::stream_handle in(io_service); 
#else 
#  error "Unsupported platform." 
#endif 

bp::child start_child() 
{ 
    std::string exec = "type \"./config.xml\""; 

    bp::context ctx; 
    ctx.stdout_behavior = bp::capture_stream(); 

    return bp::launch_shell(exec, ctx); 
} 

void end_read(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred); 

void begin_read() 
{ 
    in.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), 
        boost::bind(&end_read, ba::placeholders::error, ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred)); 
} 

void end_read(const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) 
{ 
    if (!ec) 
    { 
        std::cout << std::string(buffer.data(), bytes_transferred) << std::flush; 
        begin_read(); 
    } 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    bp::child c = start_child(); 

    bp::pistream &is = c.get_stdout(); 
    in.assign(is.handle().release()); 

    begin_read(); 

    c.wait(); 

    std::cin.get();
}
```

And I newer see anethig come out from it. Like It can not grab `type` stream at all=( (while all my other tests on say `echo` and `ping` worked like a charm)
Is there any way to make Boost.Process work with `type` command line application correctly?

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall on win32 the first arg passed to the child process is supposed to be the exe name.  I also believe that the OS eats the first parameter expecting it to be the exe name, then passes the rest on to your application.

See this: [Paths and CreateProcess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265650/paths-and-createprocess)

And this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425.aspx